# I cant connect to my Amazon ec2 running nodejs using tcp

Tags: node.js, sockets, amazon-web-services, tcp, amazon-ec2

Hi all I have created an Ubuntu EC2 instance and have installed nodejs on it.  Am running a simple node js script (which IS running and not throwing any errors:

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.write("from server\r\n");
    socket.pipe(socket);
});
server.listen(8000, "localhost");
console.log("TCP server listening on port 8000 at localhost.");
```

to test this, (am on windows) I am running a program called hercules to attempt a tcp connection, but it always comes back with tcp connection error: 10061
 and the IP address can't be pinged either.

My ec2's IP address is 54.76.31.140.  I have added an inbound tcp:8000 0.0.0.0 rule to my security group in the aws console and I have added hercules to my windows firewall and avg exceptions.  I have also added an exception to my home dsl router and finally I have checked the ubuntu iptables there are no rules set.

Pls help, I can't seem to find whats wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you tell the server to listen on "localhost," that's the only place it will listen -- "localhost" -- the loopback interface, 127.0.0.1, which is only accessible from... the local host.

Remove the 2nd argument to `server.listen()`.

http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback

If you want to be able to ping your instance, you have to allow ICMP in the security group.

Also, before you fix it, and after, run this, and note the difference in output:

```
 $ netstat -a -n | grep 8000 | grep -i tcp
```

Comment: It really was that simple, It really annoys me that all the tutorials and 'examples' iv'e seen so far use localhost for that paramater.  Like thats gonna help.